# Why does usage of lower() changes the order of resultset?

Tags: oracle10g

I have a table where I store information about users. The table has the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE PERSONS 
(
  ID NUMBER(20, 0) NOT NULL,
  FIRSTNAME VARCHAR2(40), 
  LASTNAME VARCHAR2(40),
  BIRTHDAY DATE, 
  CONSTRAINT PERSONEN_PK PRIMARY KEY 
  (ID)
  ENABLE 
);
```

After inserting some test data:

```
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into PERSONS (ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,BIRTHDAY) values ('1','Max','Mustermann',to_date('31.10.89','DD.MM.RR'));
Insert into PERSONS (ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,BIRTHDAY) values ('2','Max','Mustermann',to_date('31.10.89','DD.MM.RR'));
Insert into PERSONS (ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,BIRTHDAY) values ('3','Carl','Carlchen',to_date('01.01.12','DD.MM.RR'));
Insert into PERSONS (ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,BIRTHDAY) values ('4','Max','Mustermann',to_date('31.10.89','DD.MM.RR'));
Insert into PERSONS (ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,BIRTHDAY) values ('5','Max','Mustermann',to_date('31.10.89','DD.MM.RR'));
Insert into PERSONS (ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,BIRTHDAY) values ('6','Carl','Carlchen',to_date('01.01.12','DD.MM.RR'));
```

I want to select all duplicates of a given user. Let's use "Max Mustermann" for example:

```
SELECT p.id,p.firstname,p.lastname,p.birthday
  FROM persons p
  WHERE p.firstname = 'Max'
    AND p.lastname = 'Mustermann'
    AND p.birthday = to_date('31.10.1989','dd.mm.yyyy')
  ORDER BY p.firstname,p.lastname;
```

This gives me a result like this:

```
id  first   last        birthday
=================================
1   Max     Mustermann  31.10.89
2   Max     Mustermann  31.10.89
4   Max     Mustermann  31.10.89
5   Max     Mustermann  31.10.89
```

I want to do a case insensitive compare, so I change the query using lower (and trim) like this:

```
SELECT p.id,p.firstname,p.lastname,p.birthday
  FROM persons p
  WHERE lower(trim(p.firstname)) = lower(trim('mAx '))
    AND lower(trim(p.lastname)) = lower(trim('  musteRmann  '))
    AND p.birthday = to_date('31.10.1989','dd.mm.yyyy')
  ORDER BY p.lastname,p.firstname;
```

Now surprise the order has changed!

```
id  first   last        birthday
=================================
1   Max     Mustermann  31.10.89
5   Max     Mustermann  31.10.89
4   Max     Mustermann  31.10.89
2   Max     Mustermann  31.10.89
```

**Why does the order change, just by using lower()** (same result when using without trim())!? I can get a stable ordering by adding the id column to the ORDER BY. But shouldn't the lower() have no affect to the ordering?

Workaround by also using id column for ORDER BY:

```
SELECT p.id,p.firstname,p.lastname,p.birthday
  FROM persons p
  WHERE p.firstname = 'Max'
    AND p.lastname = 'Mustermann'
    AND p.birthday = to_date('31.10.1989','dd.mm.yyyy')
  ORDER BY p.firstname,p.lastname,p.id;

SELECT p.id,p.firstname,p.lastname,p.birthday
  FROM persons p
  WHERE lower(trim(p.firstname)) = lower(trim('mAx '))
    AND lower(trim(p.lastname)) = lower(trim('  musteRmann  '))
    AND p.birthday = to_date('31.10.1989','dd.mm.yyyy')
  ORDER BY p.lastname,p.firstname,p.id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the values to be ordered by are identical, then the DBMS is free to choose any order it feels correct (the same way it is free to choose any order if no `order by` is specified alltogether).

Because all values of the columns in the order by are identical the resulting order is not stable. The only way to get a stable order is to include a unique column as an additional order criteria for ties - exactly what you did when you added the id column.

> *Why does the order change, just by using lower()*

From a technical point, I'd guess that applying the `lower()` changed the execution plan and therefor the access path to the data.

But again (just to make sure): ordering on identical values never guarantees a stable order!

Comment: Accepting this awnswer as it is very precise on the actual problem. But giving you both an upvote, as you really helpt me both! Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

There is no ordering without an `order by clause`. Sometimes it looks like there might be (`group by` fooled a lot of people in older releases`, but it's only coincidental, and must not be relied upon. In your case you're ordering by some columns, but you expect duplicates within that ordering to be further ordered implicitly, which won't happen - or at least cannot be relied on.

In this case Oracle probably happens to be retrieving the rows for your first query in the order you inserted them purely as a side effect of how it's reading data from the blocks, and the `order by` sorts them within that set without actually changing them (or quite likely it's skipping the `order by` step internally if it realises it's pointless; the explain plan would tell you that).

If you change the order the order the records are created:

```
...
Insert into PERSONS (ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,BIRTHDAY) values
('5','Max','Mustermann',to_date('31.10.89','DD.MM.RR'));
Insert into PERSONS (ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,BIRTHDAY) values
('4','Max','Mustermann',to_date('31.10.89','DD.MM.RR'));
...
```

then the result 'order' changes too:

```
SELECT p.id,p.firstname,p.lastname,p.birthday
  FROM persons p
  WHERE p.firstname = 'Max'
    AND p.lastname = 'Mustermann'
    AND p.birthday = to_date('31.10.1989','dd.mm.yyyy')
  ORDER BY p.firstname,p.lastname;

        ID FIRSTNAME            LASTNAME             BIRTHDAY
---------- -------------------- -------------------- ---------
         1 Max                  Mustermann           31-OCT-89
         2 Max                  Mustermann           31-OCT-89
         5 Max                  Mustermann           31-OCT-89
         4 Max                  Mustermann           31-OCT-89
```

Once you have the function things are changing enough for that happy accident to go out of the window, even if the records are inserted in `id` order (which has no relevance to the DB internally). `lower()` isn't changing the ordering, you just aren't getting lucky any more.

You cannot expect or rely on an order unless you *fully* specify it in the `order by` clause.

Comment: He **is** using an `order by` he just doesn't get a stable order because the ordered values are all identical.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - yes, I referred to that later but the first para was misleading, thanks.

Comment: As @a_horse_with_no_name says, I'm indeed using an ORDER BY. So it's just not ordering the way I want, because there is no explicit order for identical data? And as soon as I add the id field there is an explicit order, right?

Comment: @elton - exactly. You might also be interested in often-linked a couple of Tom Kyte articles on ordering, like [this](http://tkyte.blogspot.co.uk/2005/08/order-in-court.html) and [this](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:74320098178823), though at least you're trying harder than most of the people he rants at... *8-)